# How to obtain the asymptotic behavior of this integral?

Tags: integration, asymptotics

Consider the integral

$$ I(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp \bigl( - s^2/2 \bigr) \cos \bigl( xs + \lambda s^3 \bigr) \, \text{d} s,$$

where $\lambda >0$ is a constant. I would like to know the asymptotic behavior of this integral in the limit $x \rightarrow \infty$. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Looks like a good place for the stationary phase method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_phase_approximation

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see, how the stationary phase method applies in this case. To bring the integral on the form used in the wiki article, we can rewrite it as $I(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} \exp(-s^2/2 + i \lambda s^3) \exp(i x s) \text{d} s$, and the function $f$ in the article is thus $f(s) = s$ for the case I am interested in. This function does not have any stationary points.

Comment: As a start, integration by parts shows that your integral is $\mathcal{O}\left(x^{-N}\right)$ for any $N>0$.

Comment: Take $s = \omega t - i/(6 \lambda)$ with $\omega = (3 \lambda)^{-1/3}$ and show that
$$I(x) =
\frac \omega 2 \int_{-\infty + i \gamma}^{\infty + i \gamma}
 e^{i t^3/3 + a t + b} dt =
\frac \omega 2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
 e^{i t^3/3 + a t + b} dt = \\
\omega \exp \left( \frac x {6 \lambda} + \frac 1 {108 \lambda^2} \right)
 \int_0^\infty \cos \left( \frac {t^3} 3 +
  \omega \left(x + \frac 1 {12 \lambda} \right) t \right) dt,$$
which gives the Airy function $\operatorname {Ai}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an elaboration on Maxim's comment. Your integral is
$$
I(x) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( { - \frac{1}{2}s^2  + i\lambda s^3  + ixs} \right)ds} .
$$
With the change of variables $s = \frac{t}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }} + \frac{1}{{6i\lambda }}$, we find
$$
I(x) \!=\! \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\exp \left( {\frac{x}{{6\lambda }} \!+\! \frac{1}{{108\lambda ^2 }}} \right)\int_{ - \infty  + i/(6\lambda )}^{ + \infty  + i/(6\lambda )} {\exp \left( {i\left( {\frac{{t^3 }}{3} \!+\! \frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\!\left( {x \!+\! \frac{1}{{12\lambda }}} \right)t} \right)} \right)dt}. 
$$
Pushing the contour downwards and using the [know integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.5.E1) of the Airy function, we deduce
\begin{align*}
I(x) & = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\exp \left( {\frac{x}{{6\lambda }} + \frac{1}{{108\lambda ^2 }}} \right)\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\exp \left( {i\left( {\frac{{t^3 }}{3} + \frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\left( {x + \frac{1}{{12\lambda }}} \right)t} \right)} \right)dt} 
\\ &  = \frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\exp \left( {\frac{x}{{6\lambda }} + \frac{1}{{108\lambda ^2 }}} \right)\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\cos \left( {\frac{{t^3 }}{3} + \frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\left( {x + \frac{1}{{12\lambda }}} \right)t} \right)dt} 
\\ & = \frac{\pi }{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\exp \left( {\frac{x}{{6\lambda }} + \frac{1}{{108\lambda ^2 }}} \right)\operatorname{Ai}\left(\frac{1}{{(3\lambda )^{1/3} }}\left( {x + \frac{1}{{12\lambda }}} \right) \right).
\end{align*}
Now we [know](http://dlmf.nist.gov/9.7.E5) that
$$
\operatorname{Ai}(z) = \frac{1}{{2\sqrt \pi  z^{1/4} }}\exp \left( {-\frac{{2z^{3/2} }}{3}} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{z^{3/2} }}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\leq \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi$). Since
$$
\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{{\sqrt {3\lambda } }}\left( {x + \frac{1}{{12\lambda }}} \right)^{3/2}  = \frac{{2x^{3/2} }}{{3\sqrt {3\lambda } }} + \frac{{x^{1/2} }}{{12\sqrt 3 \lambda ^{3/2} }} + \frac{1}{{576\sqrt 3 \lambda ^{5/2} x^{1/2} }} -  \cdots 
$$
and
$$
(3\lambda )^{1/12} \left( {x + \frac{1}{{12\lambda }}} \right)^{ - 1/4}  = (3\lambda )^{1/12} x^{ - 1/4} \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{48\lambda x}} +  \cdots } \right),
$$
we obtain
$$
I(x) = \frac{{\sqrt \pi  }}{{2(3\lambda x)^{1/4} }}\exp \left( {-\frac{{2x^{3/2} }}{{3\sqrt {3\lambda } }} + \frac{x}{{6\lambda }} - \frac{{x^{1/2} }}{{12\sqrt 3 \lambda ^{3/2} }} + \frac{1}{{108\lambda ^2 }}} \right)\left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{x^{1/2} }}} \right)} \right)
$$
as $x\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg x|\leq \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi$). More terms in the expansion can be obtained if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

(I'll denote $\lambda$ as $t$) Call your integral $u_t(x)$. Then $u$ satisfies the differential equation
$$u''-\frac{1}{3t}u'-\frac{x}{3t}u=0.$$
This follows from using integration by parts on $u'$. We will look to expand $u$ around the point $\infty$ (equivalently $u(1/x)$ around $x=0$). To do so, we let $u=e^S$, and find that the ODE turns asymptotically into
$$(S')^2\sim\frac{x}{3t},$$
meaning that $S\sim - \frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{x^{3/2}}{t^{1/2}}$ (we choose the sign of $S$ so that $u$ decays to zero for large $x$). Thus your asymptotic behavior as $x\to\infty$ should be dominated by
$$u_t(x)\sim \exp\left( -\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{x^{3/2}}{t^{1/2}}\right).$$
Here, I a not using $\sim$ in a technical sense, just abusing notation to say that this is the main contribution. You can substitute $S=-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{x^{3/2}}{t^{1/2}}+h$ into the original differential equation, where $h=o(x^{3/2})$, and you find that $h(x)=x/6$ makes the ODE consistent. So the solution is dominated by a term of the form
$$u_t(x) \sim \exp\left( -\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3}}\frac{x^{3/2}}{t^{1/2}}+x/6\right).$$
Again, I am not using $\sim$ technically here. You can keep going to obtain lower order corrections.

Edit: a second round edits were made after reading Gary and Maxim's comments.

Comment: Note that the integral is real for $x>0$.

Comment: The ODE should be $u'' - u'/(3 t) - x u/(3 t) = 0$. $S \sim C x^{3/2}$ doesn't give an asymptotic equivalence for $u$, there are other $e^{C x^p}$ factors (with $p > 0$) and a $C x^q$ factor.

Comment: How did you obtain the fact that there are other polynomial factors in the exponent? I obtained that there were none.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your great ideas! I agree with @Maxim that $I(x)$ satisfies the equation $0 = I''(x) - I'(x)/(3\lambda) - x/(3\lambda)I(x)$. Using the substitution $I(x) = \exp(x/(6\lambda)) y(x)$ it follows that $y(x)$ must satisfy a shifted Airy equation which is in line with Maxim's comment above. Combined with $Ai(z) \sim A z^{-1/4} \exp(-2/3 z^{3/2})$ for large, real $z$ this then implies that $I(x)$ must be asymptotic to something like $x^{-1/4} \exp(- B x^{3/2} + x/(6\lambda))$, where $B$ is some positive numerical factor. I will clean up my calculation to get $B$.

Comment: $h$ satisfies the ODE $3 t h'' + 3 t (h')^2 - (2 \sqrt {3 t x} + 1) h' + \sqrt {x/(3 t)} - \sqrt {3 t/x}/2 = 0.$ Taking $h = \ln x$ leaves one unbalanced term $\sqrt x$. Instead, the leading term is obtained from $-2 \sqrt {3 t x} \hspace {1.5 px} h' + \sqrt {x/(3 t)} = 0$.

Comment: Hi @Maxim and Mathias Klahn, thank you for the feedback. I redid the calculation and I now agree with you. I corrected the post.

Comment: Which boundary conditions would be used for the differential equation ? I am very interested by this approach. Thanks for answering.